# SQL query to find grandchildren of object

Tags: mysql, database

Let's suppose I have a table like this:

```
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------+
| id |   name    | surname | dad_id | mom_id  |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------+
|  1 | John      | Smith   |      2 |       3 |
|  2 | Arnold    | Smith   |      7 |       8 |
|  3 | Margaret  | Smith   |      5 |       6 |
|  4 | Junior    | Smith   |      1 |       9 |
+----+-----------+---------+--------+---------+
```

It stores people and their relations as parents-children. I am wondering how would look like a query, which will return name and surname of a person with the greatest number of grandchild. I have completely no clue where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

```
#table list of fathers and their kid names

CREATE VIEW father AS SELECT  A.mom_id, B.name, B.surname FROM tablename A JOIN tablename B ON A.id = B.dad_id FROM tablename A JOIN tablename B ON A.id = B.dad_id

#table list of mothers and their kid names

CREATE VIEW mother AS SELECT A.mom_id, B.name, B.surname FROM tablename A JOIN tablename B ON A.id = B.dad_id FROM FROM tablename A JOIN tablename B ON A.id = B.mom_id

#table of grandpas link with their sons who have kids and count how many there are, 
#each father name will be repeated if they have more than one kids, so if we count the number father 
#names attach to grandpa names, we essentially find the number of grandkids. I got a little 
#lazy here and use order by greatest count instead of returning the max count to find the grandpa with the highest grand kids.
**#This will only give you # of kids produce by your sons. You also need to add the kids produce by your daughters.**

SELECT  T.id, T.name, T.surname, father.name, COUNT(father.name) FROM father JOIN tablename T ON tablename.id = father.dad_id GROUP BY T.id ORDER BY DESC;
```

Comment: dad_id and mom_id are ids of persons in same table. These persons are real parents of that considered person. I can make another table to hold parents relations, for example table Parenthood with 2 columns: parent_id child_id if it would make things easier.

Comment: wait what? I am confused. Are you saying that the names here in this table are names of someone's child (i.e. we do not know if they are grand_kids or just kids)? The mom_id links to some female name in another table and the dad_id links to another man's name in another table?

Comment: Arr i messed things up. Let's say this table holds some group of people. In this group are many families, and each person has it's mother and father.

Comment: I see, that is difficult. We need to figure out which one of these people are grand_kids of someone and then find their parents which links to their grandparent, then count them.

Comment: Hope this guideline helps. I don't know what kind of sql you are using, but this is in MySQL i believe.

Answer (score 0):

*To get the parent with the most children, all people in the same data table*

Something like this, plus a working SQL-fiddle.
Hope this helps!

---

**SQL__List of parents ordered by count/score of kids**

```
SELECT
  parents.parent as 'parent',
  MAX(parents.count) as 'score'
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(t2.name, " ", t2.surname) as 'parent',
    count(t1.parent_id) as 'count'
  FROM (
    -- LIST parent id, kid id
      -- * list of unique pairs: dad_id and id, 
      -- * also mom_id and id
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       dad_id as 'parent_id', id,
       name, surname
    FROM family
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       mom_id as 'parent_id', id,
       name, surname
    FROM family
  ) as t1
  INNER JOIN family AS t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
  GROUP BY parent_id
  ORDER BY parent_id
) as parents
GROUP BY parents.parent
ORDER BY 'score';
```

Also if you wanted to return ONLY the first result (ie, the most parented) you could throw on "LIMIT 1" at the end or something.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90bf57/55)

Answer (score 0):

First, found the people which have a child and save it into the temporary table with their child. Then found the people whose child also have a child.

**SQL script:**

```
-- Create table
CREATE TABLE #Family
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    surname VARCHAR(30),
    dad_id INT,
    mom_id INT
)

--insert data
INSERT INTO #Family (id, name, surname, dad_id, mom_id) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', 2, 3)
INSERT INTO #Family (id, name, surname, dad_id, mom_id) VALUES (2, 'Arnold', 'Smith', 7, 8)
INSERT INTO #Family (id, name, surname, dad_id, mom_id) VALUES (3, 'Margaret', 'Smith', 5, 6)
INSERT INTO #Family (id, name, surname, dad_id, mom_id) VALUES (4, 'Junior', 'Smith', 1, 9)


-- Find people With child and save it into temporary table #FGTwo (family generation two)
SELECT * INTO #FGTwo FROM
(SELECT f.id, f.name, f.surname, f.dad_id, f.mom_id, 
fd.id cid, fd.name cname, fd.surname csurname, fd.dad_id cdad_id, fd.mom_id cmom_id
FROM #Family f
INNER JOIN #Family fd ON fd.dad_id = f.id
UNION ALL
SELECT f.id, f.name, f.surname, f.dad_id, f.mom_id, 
fm.id cid, fm.name cname, fm.surname csurname, fm.dad_id cdad_id, fm.mom_id cmom_id
FROM #Family f
INNER JOIN #Family fm ON fm.mom_id = f.id) AS FG2

--Uncomment next line to see people With their child
-- select * from #FGTwo

-- Find people With Grandchild and save it into temporary table #PeopleWithGrandchildren
SELECT * INTO #PeopleWithGrandchildren FROM
(SELECT f2.id, f2.name, f2.surname
from #FGTwo f2
INNER JOIN #Family fd ON fd.dad_id = f2.cid
UNION ALL
SELECT f2.id, f2.name, f2.surname
FROM #FGTwo f2
INNER JOIN #Family fm ON fm.mom_id = f2.cid) pwg

--Uncomment next line to see people With their child
-- select * from #PeopleWithGrandchildren

-- Finds all people having the same maximal number of grandchildren
DECLARE @MaxCount INT
SET @MaxCount = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(id) AS MaxCount FROM #PeopleWithGrandchildren GROUP BY id ORDER BY MaxCount DESC)

SELECT name, surname FROM #PeopleWithGrandchildren 
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT GC.id FROM 
(SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS GCount FROM #PeopleWithGrandchildren GROUP BY id) GC
WHERE GCount = @MaxCount)
--If you want to select only one use the "SELECT TOP 1 " instead of "SELECT *"

-- drop all temporary tables
drop table #Family
drop table #FGTwo
drop table #PeopleWithGrandchildren
```

**Output:**

```
name        surname
Arnold      Smith
Margaret    Smith
```